# how to code some atom's atomic number and atomic mass number

Tags: html

I want to know how to code some atom's atomic number and atomic mass number in line
  also I tried this

```
<sup>35</sup><sub>17</sub>Cl
```

It is like this [I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22hM7.png)

But I want like this [Chlorine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOU1W.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using the sup and sub tags.
Use the following CSS rules instead:

HTML:

```
<p><span class="atoms">17</span>Cl</p>
```

CSS:

```
p { line-height: 1.5 }

.atoms {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.3em;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 0.8em;
 }
```

Edit: You can do something similar for **mass number**. 
HTML:

```
      <p><span class="mass">35</span><span 
      class="atoms">17</span>Cl</p>
```

CSS:

```
 .mass{
  position: relative;
  bottom:0.7em;
  left:1em;
  color:blue;
  font-size:0.8em;
 }
```